# Migrate WordPress website integrated with SHOPEXPRESS from one host to another

Tags: wordpress, migrate

I have a WordPress website integrated with SHOPEXPRESS on one server. Now I want to move this to another server. How can I do this?

Comment: Have you researched this at all? Have you tried migrating a copy of your live site/database to a test server?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.